# how to put two input box value to be inserted in url

Tags: jquery, html

here is the code I've got and it is working fine...

```
onChange="location.href='patient_page.php?date='+document.getElementById('sd').valueI"
```

i need to have two value in the url parameter like this for example, but this is not working.

```
onChange="location.href='patient_page.php?date='+document.getElementById('sd').value;+&+'service='+document.getElementById('sd').value;"
```

how to properly write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

```
onChange="location.href='patient_page.php?date='+document.getElementById('sd').value+'&service='+document.getElementById('sd').value;"
```